# How to create VCS-like conflict-merging file?

Tags: merge, diff

I'm trying to generate "unresolved-conflict"-like files with no luck.

I checked `diff` manpage and googled about diff, merging etc... but I only found information about how to handle these files, but not about how to actually generate them.

To be clear, what I am trying to do is, having two similar files, generate single automatically merged one similar to that most VCS systems like Git or Subversion generate over files in "conflict" status.

The main goal is be able to rapidly edit it to manually resolve all differences just as I do in Git or Subversion but without having them in any VCS system.

I "almost" successfully generated full diffs with `diff -C 1000000`command (because I won't have too large files that context limit is pretty acceptable).

...but resulting file comes with ALL rows modified. That is: prepended by "-" or "+" (depending of if it comes from first or second file) or " " (space) for common rows.

What I would obtain is an "almost unchanged" file with sections like following example emphasizing differences:

```
<<<<<<<< File1
Section from File1
Foo
========
Section from File2
Bar
>>>>>>>> File2
```

**EDIT:**

Answering @s.m. comment, I explain here what is my exact goal (because it is too long to explain in a comment):

I'm working on a server to allocate multiple PostgreSQL clusters acting as hot-stanby of distinct masters.

I already successfully implemented binary full/incremental backups (bacula) over production servers and also have a helper script to configure hot-standby servers.

But nowadays we have to setup (and mantain -and ideally periodically check-) all of them one by one.

To make it simpler, we are planning to create single (or possibly multiple) "Super"-hot-standby server(s) containing multiple clusters replicating different master servers.

My goal is to have a single script to create new standby cluster easily without too complicated tunning and not having to bother about backup setup (because all clusters will be backed up at once).

I almost successfully implemented that script: It creates a new cluster in a free port, adjust needed configuration parameters and put it in sync with master.

These adjustmens are made over "default" configuration files but some masters may have special configuration parameters (specially memory adjustments) that must be replicated in standby because, otherwise, it could be unable to replicate some operations of the master). And there is too the pg_haba.conf which defines which users/servers are allowed to connect to, which we also want to replicate on standby (for an eventual failover).

So, to make it easier (and less error prone) to merge both configuration files, I implemented a bash function to retrieve configuration files from masters and, now, my goal is to merge it with forementioned "default-tuned" one.

This way, adding new standby would be as easy as executing our script providing master's network name and reviewing automatically merged files to manually solve the few differences encountered in merge.

**EDIT 2:**

To be clear, what I were trying to do in preference order is:

1. Approach it by just using GNU Diff (like @s.m. pointed in his comment) even by using complex arguments or piping to external tools usually available on most unix* systems so I can wrap it in a bash function and use it in my script without no dependencies.
2. Use some existing tool (but not reinvent the wheel).
3. Implement my own tool and use it.

Comment: So you would like to obtain a file that looks like that... *how*, exactly? Just by using `diff`? Or are you writing a program to do it? Not that I'm an expert, but I think those markers are put there by the VCS you're using. In the case of Mercurial, if it's of any help, the job is done [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/tip/mercurial/filemerge.py) and [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/tip/mercurial/simplemerge.py).

Comment: I'm trying to do it in bash script. Its quite large to explain, so I added an "edit" section to the question to explain it better. Btw, thanks for your answer. I will review your links now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without better solution, I finally tried to implement my own tool (which I called 'humandiff') to approach it.

I published it in [Github](https://github.com/bitifet/humandiff) and uploaded as [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/humandiff) so I can now install it from npm in producion servers.

Even thought it needs a little setup to be installed. That is:

- Install NodeJS and NPM (`sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm` in debian-like systems).
- Install *humandiff* itself (`sudo npm install -g humandiff`).

Usage and output examples can be found in [README file](https://github.com/bitifet/humandiff#readme) so I do'nt extend myself anymore.

I post this answer just in case someone happens to have the same problem but, anyway, better solutions would be welcomed too.

**Edit:** I missed to say, even it's pretty obvious, that in fact I didn't implement any diff algorithm at all. I just noticed that having position and offset metatata provided by *GNU diff* and one of the original files is possible to construct the other or that *merged* file a were searching for so I simply implemented a wrapper to de so. But, instead of calling *GNU Diff* binary, I found an also named "diff" module in the *NPM* repository that served to me for the same task.